# Rail 4 image_tag with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a show page that displays an image based on the person called out of the database. My current code looks like this :

```
    <%= image_tag('DAF_520x222.jpg') %>
```

I want to exchange the 'DAF_520x222' portion for a call of @user_name but I am unsure of how to go about putting this in the image_tag itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly interpolate it into the string. It will automatically change it to its value

```
<%= image_tag("#{@user_name}.jpg") %>
```

This should work

Comment: I have tried this and I am getting this from the server...

        ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/.jpg"):

Comment: @lostrennie That means the variable `@user_name` is blank. In your question you specified using this variable – make sure its defined before using this code.

Comment: You were correct, I forgot to append the user_name variable. It is working now! Thank you so much for your help!